# How to add the checked="checked" attribute to the output of .html() method

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, attr

There must be something special about the checked attribute of a checkbox either at the jQuery level or the DOM level.  With this HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="cb" type="checkbox" />
    </body>
</html>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
$(function() {

    $("#cb").attr("checked","checked");
    alert("Expecting this HTML fragment to have a 'checked' attribute:\n\n"
          + $("body").html());

});
```

I'm not getting what I expect; if I use an attribute name besides "checked" it works as expected.

The reason I'm trying to get this to work is I need to get the HTML as it exists in a browser DOM and convert it to PDF, so users can get PDF versions of the page as it is as they're looking at it; it's manipulated heavily on the client side, so getting the correct HTML directly from the server is not an easy option.

Here's a working version of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/pettys/qTfDP/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Update to jQuery 1.6](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/qTfDP/3/).  There have been some [significant changes to `attr`](http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-16-and-attr/) in 1.6/1.6.1.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the link, too - glad to know the background.

Comment: @pettys I think the underlying problem is that until 1.6 `attr` was setting the DOM property `checked` without adding the attribute in the markup.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the distinction between setting attributes and setting properties until I read the link you had sent.  Good stuff!